# Datanucleus Google App Engine One-To-Many relationship

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa-2.0, datanucleus

I've got following code:

```
@Entity
public class Incident {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.encoded-pk", value="true")
    private String incidentId;

    @Persistent
    @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.pk-id", value="true")
    private Long keyId;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy="incident")
    @OrderBy("requestId")
    @JoinColumn(name="INCIDENT_ID")
    public List<ServiceRequest> requests;

    ...
}

@Entity
public class ServiceRequest {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.encoded-pk", value="true")
    private String requestId;

    @Persistent
    @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.pk-id", value="true")
    private Long keyId;
    private Incident incident;

    ...
}
```

Scenario of using it is firstly create and persist ServiceRequest and then create a Incident and add to it existing ServiceRequest - but when I tried to persist an Incident I've got following error
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Object with id "agxzbWFydGNpdHlhZ2hyFAsSDlNlcnZpY2VSZXF1ZXN0GAEM" is managed by a different Object Manager

Comment: And the "existing Service Request" is managed by a different EntityManager, which you can easily check by using methods on the EM to see what it is managing. If detached it isn't managed by anything

Comment: So there is no possibility to add existing (already persisted) object to new one ? Or maybe I could somehow attach it to my Incident ?

Comment: Of course there's the possibility .... WHEN it is managed by the same EntityManager (like the JPA spec says). You give no info where you got this existing object from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll sugest you to start as follows, and then tell you to study deeply the doc regarding all the datastore, JDO Stuff. Then thank Google. :-)

You must use the same persistence manager to do all your read / create / save / update tasks at once. Meaning that in the same method or code block, you have to :

- Get a fresh PersistenceManager
- fetch the EntityA you need
- do whatever you want with it, including instantiating other Entities from other Classes and have them all linked somehow
- use the pm to persist everything
- close the pm

The thing is, if you work with more than one Entity, you need to use the same PersistenceManager instance.

[JDO doc - Google](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/)

Comment: OK - It worked :). But instead of PersistentManager I'm using EntityManager - is there a difference between using those two ? And now I've got another problem - when I've tried to fetch my "Incidents" from the database their request field was null. I'm geting their using code `EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager(); 
Query q = em.createQuery("select i from Incident i order by incidentId");
List<Incident> list = q.getResultList();` I've also tried to change request field from public to private and create proper setter and getter - but still It is not working

Comment: It is working. When you have your List<Incident>, the Request field is null until you access it (before you close the EntityManager !) just access it and it will be loaded on the fly. It's called lazy loading, a technology to spare resources. read my answer to [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643902/how-to-auto-fetch-jdo-nested-collection-of-entities/11204780#11204780)